# Android - How to show a loading image while the adapter is loading the images?

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask

I'm writing an android application that download images from a server but I want to show a loading image while the image is loading in the adapter.
This is my adapter:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public ImageView imageView;
private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private int imageWidth;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filePaths,
        int imageWidth,Context context1) {

    this._activity = activity;
    this._filePaths = filePaths;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    this.context=context1;

}

public int getCount() {
    return this._filePaths.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this._filePaths.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallery_image);

   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
          imageWidth));
  Log.e("Position",position+"");
    new RetreiveBitMap().execute(_filePaths.get(position));

return imageView;
}

class RetreiveBitMap extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Bitmap> {

    private Exception exception;
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        URL myFileUrl =null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
        try {
            myFileUrl= new URL(urls[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {

            String encodedfilename = Base64.encodeToString(urls[0].getBytes(),0);

        //Controllo presenza della cache
        try {
        InputStream check = context.openFileInput(encodedfilename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Se non presente, scarico il file

        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
         //Salvataggio cache
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(encodedfilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ( (len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        fos.write(buffer,0, len1);
        }

        fos.close();
        }

         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput(encodedfilename),null,options);


        } catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("errore download",e.getMessage());
        } 
        return bm;

    } 
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spinner);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imageBit) {

        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBit);
    }
}
}
```

This adapter show the loading images but only the last of the grid change into the downloaded image and it is in the wrong position because it should be the first of the grid.

Comment: Initially use progressbar. As soon as image is downloaded in onPostExecute hide progressbar & show image

Comment: It's very simple. Try to load your LOADING image into `AsyncTask`  `onPreExecute()` and  load your main image into `onPostExecute()` after download completed

Comment: `onPreExecute` show the default image on Imageview and on `onPostExecute` after the background process completes show the original image on Imageview.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this like: implement your `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` like below:

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spinner);//Loading image 

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imageBit) {

 if(imagefit!=null){
    imageView.setBitmap(imagefit);//Final image
   }
}
```

Comment: @M D  Ok now I can see the spinner image on all the imageView but only the last of the grid change into the downloded image and it isn't in the right place because it should be the first of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the universal Image Loading Library like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) . It can load images very fastly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Picasso** library by *Square*.

> http://square.github.io/picasso/

This library gives you the option of placeholders while it does the necesary networking to download the image. No need for Asynctask here if you load the images on your custom adapter.

This line will do the trick

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .placeholder(R.id.placeholder)
  .error(R.id.placeholder_error)
  .into(imageView)
```

You can also access to resize options with `.resize(width, height)` and `.centerCrop()` or `.fit()`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

OK in your AsyncTask override `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` like this

```
Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //initialize inflate and customize your dialog
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.youricon);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
}
```

See this for
[How to create a Custom Progress Dialog over riding the default one in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745428/how-to-create-a-custom-progress-dialog-over-riding-the-default-one-in-android)

Hope it helps cheers :)